# Why react-bootstrap doesn't work in vitejs(reactjs)? how to use ract- bootstrap in vitejs dev tool? Note:asking about react-bootstrap, not bootstrapv5

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, vite

```
import React from 'react'

import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap'

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <>
    <div className='home'>
      
     <Button variant="primary">Primary</Button>[See in image that primary doesn't work][1]
     
      
    </div>
  </>

    
    
  )
}


export default Home;
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: code Url: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-9pbtfk?file=src/App.jsx                   please notice output in stackblitz url. There is all Button , Accordion doesn't work . u can notice in output. Tell me anyone how to fix it

Comment: How is this question different from [your other question posted at a similar time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74233860/how-to-use-react-bootstrap-in-vitejs)? Please don't ask the same question multiple times, if that's happened. (I did try to clean up the other question a bit -- the stackblitz link was helpful.) Voting to close as dupe re: [this suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278511/1028230).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use react-bootstrap in viteJs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74233860/how-to-use-react-bootstrap-in-vitejs)